# how to clear the errors when starting symfony framework in windows with apache

Tags: php, apache, symfony

I am new to symfony framework, I would like to learn about it ..
So,I have installed it through shell and I started its server by  "`php app/console server:run`" command .

and when I tried 'localhost:8000' I got an error message like,

```
InvalidArgumentException in InvalidArgumentException.php line 88:
Invalid \$notFoundCallback given: must be a callable, "unknown type" given
```

and when refresh again,I'm getting another error message like,

```
LogicException in Autoloader.php line 88:
Illegal value passed (no array or string given)
```

I restarted it a lot of time but still the same effect..

the steps I have done yet now.
1. downloaded symfony and paste it in my directory.
2. instlled the composer and symfony in that directory
3.create a new project using "`php symfony.phar new myproject`" command.
4.then typed "http:localhost:8000" in the address bar of my browser,but that time it shows the error..

[image]

[image]

Please help me. Thanks in advance....

Comment: Does it work with Apache or any other server? (`php app/console server:run` is a built-in server)

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this error by turn off  php eAccelerator. To turn off php eAccelerator add following line in your project .htaccess file so that will not affect on other projects as well.

```
php_flag eaccelerator.enable 0
php_flag eaccelerator.optimizer 0
```